# What is the actual time limit between refresh of reviews?

Tags: support

I spent a bit of time this morning reviewing, and did 20. Apprently this is the limit, so I was set a time limit before I could review again. The time limit was 16 hours. (I think)

Basically, my question is, what is the time limit between filling up reviews and starting to review again? I was given what I thought was a 16 hour time limit, however this doesn't seem like a particularly round number, I would expect something more like 24 hours? Or even 12 hours?

Also, is the time limit the same between users? Does it reset quicker for users with more rep?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like voting and other limits, it is per day period.

An SE day starts at 0:00 UTC.

Comment: Changed it. I'm still to used to GMT.

Comment: just finished my remaining 6, it says 14 hours left. So you were correct.